# How to choose hyper-parameter for Gaussian Process kernels?

Tags: svm, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

I'm trying to fit Gaussian Process in scikit-learn, and start with using `kernel = RBF_1 + RBF_2 + whitekernel`(sum of two RBF kernels with different length_scale and one whitekernel capturing noise).

This kernel gives me a fitting results that is OK, but not very good. To improve the model, people kindly suggested me to **adjust the range of hyper-parameters in a reasonable range regarding my domain knowledge on the data**.

However, **I don't understand what the RBF kernel hyper-parameters mean and how they related to my data. Can anyone explain this a little bit?** I usually scale my X features to normal distribution (zero mean and unit variance) before fitting.